# Using the tap event in a custom Angular2 component

Tags: javascript, angular

I am building a component in Angular2 and I want to use the (tap) event as my own.  When I try, my app mentions using hammer.js - but I want to use my own tap, not the one provided by hammer.js - is there a way to do that?

```
(tap)='onTap($event)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I found a solution to this:

https://medium.com/@TheLarkInn/creating-custom-dom-events-in-angular2-f326d348dc8b
https://medium.com/@TheLarkInn/hacking-angular2-binding-multiple-dom-events-f781b14ef676